# question about using Insert where not exists instead of if not exists then

Tags: sql-server, performance, insert

I have a procedure that insert data to table where the data doesn't exists.

right now it's done in two steps :

1. check if the data exists already,
2. if not, insert it

i want to change it to do INSERT where not exists
as proposed in this article
it should improve performance.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/the-insert-if-not-exists-challenge-a-solution/

Here are the procedures :

1. Current proceudre

```
ALTER     PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddTest_IfInsert]
(     
    @CorrelationId uniqueidentifier,
    @TransactionId BIGINT
)  
AS  
BEGIN   
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM dbo.Test 
                    WHERE [CorrelationId] = @CorrelationId and TransactionId = @TransactionId
                   )  
     BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO dbo.Test 
        (CorrelationId,TransactionId)
        values (@CorrelationId,@TransactionId)

        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ResultId
    END 
    ELSE 
        SELECT 0 AS ResultId
END
```

2. New procedure :

```
CREATE OR ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddTest_WhereInsert]
(     
    @CorrelationId uniqueidentifier,
    @TransactionId BIGINT
)  
AS  
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO dbo.Test 
    (CorrelationId,TransactionId)
    select 
    @CorrelationId,
    @TransactionId
    from dbo.Test 
    where  not exists (select top 1 1
            FROM dbo.Test WITH (NOLOCK)  
            where CorrelationId = @CorrelationId
                    AND TransactionId = @TransactionId
                    ) 

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0 AS ResultId
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ResultId
    END
END
```

Here is the Test table that i work with :

```
CREATE TABLE Test 
(
    Id BIGINT Identity(1,1) ,
    CorrelationId uniqueidentifier,
    TransactionId BIGINT
)
```

Here are my problems with the new procedure:

1. If i try to run it for the first time on a empty table
   It doesn't insert any data.
   only when i insert the first row it starts inserting data.
   Here is my code :

```
DECLARE @CorrelationId nvarchar(100) = 'C0E68827-CC46-4A16-BEDE-B3D98D21AFFA'
DECLARE @TransactionId BIGINT        = 4

exec [dbo].[AddTest_WhereInsert] @CorrelationId,@TransactionId
```

then i inserted data :

```
DECLARE @CorrelationId nvarchar(100) = 'C0E68827-CC46-4A16-BEDE-B3D98D21AFFA'
DECLARE @TransactionId BIGINT        = 4

INSERT INTO dbo.Test 
(CorrelationId,TransactionId)
values (@CorrelationId,@TransactionId)
```

and i try to run it again it starts inserting data.

```
DECLARE @CorrelationId nvarchar(100) = 'D0E68827-CC46-4A16-BEDE-B3D98D21AFFA'
DECLARE @TransactionId BIGINT        = 5

exec [dbo].[AddTest_WhereInsert] @CorrelationId,@TransactionId
```

don't understand why is that?

2. Problem number 2 : when i start inserting data, after the second insert it inserts duplicate data.
   [image]

then i run

```
DECLARE @CorrelationId nvarchar(100) = 'E0E68827-CC46-4A16-BEDE-B3D98D21AFFA'
DECLARE @TransactionId BIGINT        = 8

exec [dbo].[AddTest_WhereInsert] @CorrelationId,@TransactionId
select * from dbo.Test
```

and this is the result:
[image]

why does it insert duplicate data?
what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go that route then you can use

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test
            (CorrelationId,
             TransactionId)
SELECT @CorrelationId,
       @TransactionId
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   dbo.Test WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
                   WHERE  CorrelationId = @CorrelationId
                          AND TransactionId = @TransactionId)
```

The `FROM dbo.Test` in your original code is a mistake and explains why you get no rows inserted when the table is empty and too many rows inserted when it already has multiple rows.

You can do a `SELECT` without a `FROM`.

In the case that the row does *not* exist when the subquery is evaluated then the `HOLDLOCK` hint will lock the range where it would exist.

Without locking the range it is still possible for two concurrent executions to both run the subquery and conclude the row does not exist and proceed to try and insert it.

The `UPDLOCK` hint in conjunction with this means that one of the transactions will encounter blocking trying to lock the range - rather than allowing both to succeed and then waiting for the deadlock monitor to kick in after deadlock ensues when they both try and upgrade their `S` locks.

The above talk of "ranges" does assume that you have a suitable index that such a range lock can be acquired on. The screenshot in the question shows that duplicates exist for `CorrelationId, TransactionId`.

You should add a unique index on this anyway so that (amongst other benefits)

- Duplicates are never possible
- The `EXISTS` check can be done as an index seek.
- The key range locked can be minimal and not just fall back to locking the whole table as no suitable index.

I also changed `select top 1 1` to `SELECT *`.

SQL Server already knows that it only needs to read a single row from the semi join without the `top 1` and selecting the constant `1` in this context is treated the same as selecting `*`.

Comment: Many thanks for the informative solution. I did not know you can run a SELECT without a FROM... Also i will read more about the hints you suggested as i didn't use that one before. Do you think it would help the performance on this case?

Comment: For performance you need an index on `CorrelationId, TransactionId` so it doesn't have to scan the whole table to see if there are duplicates. And this should be declared as unique whilst you are at it. With that in place you'll just have to test performance. If you expect attempts to insert duplicates to be quite rare then simply optimistically trying the insert and catching any duplicate key exception could be best